# Why is setting initial field values not working in django admin?

Tags: django, django-views, django-admin

I have some code that doesn't do what I would expect even after thorough debugging.

I have

```
class AgregatororderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   ...
```

on which I call

```
def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context = None):
    if self.form.base_fields["ProcessingPersonAdminId"].initial == None:
        self.form.base_fields["ProcessingPersonAdminId"].initial = request.user.id
        self.form.base_fields["ProcessingPersonName"].initial = request.user.username
    ...
    return super().change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context=extra_context, )
```

when I check, the initial values, it is set correctly. But in the admin change view it does not display.
I would appreciate any hint on why the changes are not applied.

Comment: what error are you facing ???

Comment: None at all ...

Comment: Are you trying to create an object? `change_view` only gets called on the model instance editing page

Comment: I was not, only tried to set initial values but I have done it differently in the end. This may be considered closed, thank you for you help.